# PHP: Having trouble displaying data of csv file in a table in the webpage

Tags: php, html, file, csv

I'm trying to read data from a CSV file and display it in a table. However, instead of being displayed in multiple columns, all the data are being displayed in a single column.

At first I've created a form and recorded the input in the CSV file in the following way:

```
<?php
# save the form data in csv file
$myfile = fopen("data.csv", "a+");
foreach ($_POST as $key) {
    fputcsv($myfile, explode(",", $key));
}
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Then I've created a table using html and read from the file in the following way:

```
    <div class="container">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Email</th> 
                <th>Password</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            # read from the csv file
            $f = fopen("data.csv", "r");
            while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
                echo "<tr>\n";
                foreach ($line as $cell) {
                    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>\n";
            }
            fclose($f);
            echo "\n</table>";
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Here's what I'm getting as output:
[image]

As you can see, all the input are in single column But I want the username, email and password in their respective column.

Comment: You do not show `var_dump($_POST)` and/or the HTML `<form>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are writing all your form data values onto separate lines in your first piece of code, so you are only reading back one value at a time in the second piece of code. You need to change

```
foreach ($_POST as $key) {
    fputcsv($myfile, explode(",", $key));
}
```

to

```
fputcsv($myfile, $_POST);
```